# Why some write "an" in "an bosonic"?

Tags: terminology

Recently I got corrected by other person from "a bosonic bath" to "an bosonic bath" (neither of us is a native speaker). That sounds weird to me, and does not look according to the rules I learned back in school. However, a Google search reveals that the "an" variant also sees some use. One can also find "an bosonic field theory", "an bosonic integer quantum Hall state", "an bosonic cloud" etc used. What is the motivation for that? And what variant should be considered correct?

There is a related question about "an yearly" used in some old literature, [Why is it "an yearly"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46323/why-is-it-an-yearly). There, as far as I understood, it can be explained as i) before the Great Vocal Shift, "yearly" was pronounced "eerly", so that's why "an yearly" in older writing ii) the one and only form of indefinite article was "an" long ago, and that form has been preserved in formal language for a longer time. The first explanation does not fit "an bosonic" at all. The second one somehow fits, but... It feels then that some people want to sound more formal and archaic, despite the fact that their language is full of new words.

EDIT: There was a request for "authoritative sources" for the "an bosonic" usage and a claim that Google Ngrams does not find this variant (maybe because of that my question was marked as "off-topic"?). As I mentioned, usages of "an bosonic" can be Googled. Of them, I found three interesting occurences:

1. "an bosonic integer quantum Hall phase" in the text of [Phys. Rev. Lett. 110, 046801](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.110.046801) by T. Senthil and Michael Levin, of MIT and University of Maryland respectively. Physical Review journals are published by the American Physical Society and the papers there are edited rather thoroughly (but maybe not ideally).
2. "an bosonic bath" right in the abstract of [Quantum 6, 691 (2022)](https://quantum-journal.org/papers/q-2022-04-15-691/) by Rahul Trivedi, Kevin Fischer, Shanhui Fan, and Jelena Vuckovic, of whom Kevin Fischer is of Stanford University. Quantum is an international journal, with some of the [editors](https://quantum-journal.org/about/people/) most probably native speakers.

Interestingly, I have also found two cases when a paper preprint published on arXiv contains "an bosonic" which then was edited away in the published version. Both papers are from the European New Journal Of Physics. Also, there is a thesis from the University of California, Berkley with two versions found online, and in one of them "an bosonic gas" is edited away.

Maybe occurrences of "an bosonic" are merely mistakes that accidentally passed through an editor...

Comment: Can you provide links to authoritative sources where "an bosonic" is used? A cursory search shows that the expected "a bosonic" is used.

Comment: Google Ngrams finds no results for _an bosonic_. (NB It's better to say "Neither of us is a native speaker".)

Comment: What was the other person's reasoning?

Comment: "An yearly" might have been an oversight when editing "an annual" and neglecting to tailor the article.

Comment: @KateBunting, thanks for suggestion, I introduced it in the edited version

Comment: They are almost certainly all typographical errors.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the reasoning behind closing this as 'needing research'. The OP did much more than reasonable due diligence. Please, close voters, stop with the empty button pushing for questions you don't like!

Comment: If the original statement were *an Ohmic bosonic bath* and *Ohmic* was dropped, *an bosonic bath* would be a possible typo. Is this possible? In any case this does appear to be a typo, unless someone believes the *b* is silent.

Comment: It's almost certainly a mistake. Something I see in papers is e.g. "an *f* boson" with the *f* in a different font and often not aligned with the other words. If you attempt to automatically extract text from the document (either by OCR or by attempting to parse a PDF or similar format), it is quite likely that the *f* will be missed or be out of sequence, giving "an boson". Document formats like PDF are notoriously hard to convert back to plain text: you'll get all the words but not necessarily in the right order. I would post an answer but it's really off topic.

Comment: People say "an yearly"? Not in my experience or according to this [Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+yearly%2C+an+yearly&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3). As you are a non-native speaker, I suggest you  post on English Language Learners, and do some research of your own first. This question is without value here.

Comment: @David You can check the research I've done: it's in my post. As for "an yearly", there is a link in my post to another English Language & Usage question about the use of "an yearly" in older literature including a book by Adam Smith. The accepted answer to it includes a link to the relevant Google ngram showing some usage of "an yearly" in the 18th century. So I suggest that the responsible persons read the posts of the others more attentively. And while I don't mind my question being migrated to English Language Learners, I don't think it has absolutely no value where I originally posted it.

Comment: I think the reason to migrate this question, "because it can be answered by speakers of other languages learning English", is wrong. No, it can't be answered by speakers of other languages. I was not able to distinguish typos in published papers by native speakers from some strange archaic uses like "an yearly" by Adam Smith. I think other non-natives won't be able to do that too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably just a mistake in most cases. Mistakes in the use of *a/an* can arise from typos or from editing (e.g. if someone wrote "an integer quantum Hall phase" and then added "bosonic" without remembering to change *an* to *a*). It does not sound more formal and archaic to me, and I would bet most native speakers would also not think of it that way.

Comment: So, yes, in our case it was also a mistake. Most probably, there was another word before "bosonic".